# How to properly use Selenium's java library in Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android-studio, selenium-webdriver

I've created a new project with only a blank activity in Android Studio to make sure that all [Selenium 2.52.0 java libraries](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.52/)(selenium-java-2.52.0.zip) were installed correctly. I placed those libraries in the lib folder of my project, but when  i run the MainActivity, i get the following errors:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
File1: /home/diego/AndroidStudioProjects/tentativa4/app/libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar
File2: /home/diego/AndroidStudioProjects/tentativa4/app/libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
File3: /home/diego/AndroidStudioProjects/tentativa4/app/libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar
File4: /home/diego/AndroidStudioProjects/tentativa4/app/libs/httpmime-4.5.jar
```

Doing a little search around, i managed to get around by including packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    } in my build.gradle file. However, after that i get a ton of errors( can't show everything, too big):

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will      incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably    produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.DefaultErrorHandlingPolicies$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.OperatorExpression$1$Decode) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler 
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004 
Error:...while parsing cst 012c at offset 00000afe
Error:...while parsing cst 00a5 at offset 00000316
Error:...while parsing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/ParserForXMLSchema.class
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task       ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    java.lang.RuntimeException:   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 29.707 secs
Information:1.183 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

[I managed do this test](http://qaautomated.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/setting-up-selenium-webdriver-in.html), but now i want to use the libraries to my project's ends. Do i need to do something else to work with these libraries in my project?

Comment: That link at the end just made a plain Java class. It didn't build Selenium into an app

Comment: Yes, i wanted to first make a plain java class like that to see if with Selenium webdriver i could make a web scraping of an url, and it worked great. However, after including the libs, the build always failed.